# Searching a list in Python for a certain element and string inside element

Tags: python, string, list

I've imported a 54,000 line log into Python using `readlines()`. I need to pull a variable number of lines from the log to capture server make, and firmware revisions. For example, here are 3 lines from the log:

```
# racadm getversion
<Server>    <iDRAC Version>        <Blade Type>     <Gen>   <Updatable> 
server-1    1.57.57 (Build 04)     PowerEdge M620   iDRAC7       Y
server-2    1.57.57 (Build 04)     PowerEdge M620   iDRAC7       Y
```

`racadm getversion` only occurs 1 time in the log. There can be anywhere from 1 server to 32 servers listed. I need to parse this log to capture the iDRAC version and server version, then save those to class attributes for my blade class (`self.iDRAC`, `self.model`). There are other things I need to capture, but I should be able to apply this same concept.

How could I add a line to say (following is not my actual code, just a rough example):

```
if line in cmc.log == "# racadm getversion":
    cmclist.next()
    while line == "server-"
        #do stuff to capture firmware
```

Comment: give real working inputs for help

Comment: The question may not be as helpful as it ought to be, I just don't have access to my code files at this point in time. I was hoping for a broader explanation so that I can teach myself, as opposed to getting a flat answer, if that helps in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear but is this anywhere along the right lines?

As a brief aside, I don't know whether you delimit fields with tabs or four consecutive spaces, so I handle both cases with the regular expression `(\s{4}|\t)`. You can change this if you need.

```
import re

DATA = \
"""<Server>    <iDRAC Version>        <Blade Type>     <Gen>   <Updatable>
server-1    1.57.57 (Build 04)     PowerEdge M620   iDRAC7       Y
server-2    1.57.57 (Build 04)     PowerEdge M620   iDRAC7       Y"""


class Blade(object):
    def __init__(self, model, idrac):
        self.model = model
        self.idrac = idrac

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Blade (model={}, idrac={})'.format(self.model, self.idrac)


def parse_data(data):
    for line in data.splitlines()[1:]:
        model, idrac = re.split(r'(\s{4}|\t)', line)[:2]
        yield Blade(model, idrac)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for blade in parse_data(DATA):
        print(blade)
```

**Output**

```
Blade (model=server-1, idrac=1.57.57 (Build 04))
Blade (model=server-2, idrac=1.57.57 (Build 04))
```

Comment: This is absolutely the direction I need to be moving in. We handle a lot of blade chassis and by extension, a lot of blades. Ultimately, this will be capturing networking fabrics, BIOS, iDRAC, and similar files for storage nodes and switch information. I think this will give me the tools to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a line like this

```
server-1    1.57.57 (Build 04)     PowerEdge M620   iDRAC7       Y
```

you can use `split()` to seperate each part out to an array. By default `split()` will separate the string by any whitespace. But it looks like your string has some fields that have spaces in them. you could split it over a tab (if that's how the string is separated) something like this:

```
for line in cmclist:
    separated=line.split("\t")
    version=separated[1]
```

here `line.split("\t")` should give you:

```
["server-1", "1.57.57 (Build 04)", "PowerEdge M620", "iDRAC7", "Y"]
```

you can look up more about `split()`[here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Comment: You are correct in saying that the log has spaces and not tabs. I figured I would end up needing to leverage split(), so confirmation is excellent. saving to self.iDRAC for each blade is something I need to make happen, but it looks like Tagc's suggestion will give me what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea with the `next` call. Create an iterator for the list and then use `for`, `next` or helpers in `itertools` to run through it. iterators remember their position so if you drop out of a loop early, they just restart at the next item. Here are a couple of examples with `itertools`. The second one uses `yield from` which is a python 3 thing.

```
import itertools

cmclog = """other stuff
other stuff
# racadm getversion
<Server>    <iDRAC Version>        <Blade Type>     <Gen>   <Updatable> 
server-1    1.57.57 (Build 04)     PowerEdge M620   iDRAC7       Y
server-2    1.57.57 (Build 04)     PowerEdge M620   iDRAC7       Y
other stuff
other stuff""".split("\n")

def scan_server_list(cmclog):
    server_list = []
    icmc = iter(cmclog)
    try:
        # drop everything through the racadm sentinal
        next(itertools.dropwhile(
            lambda line: not line.startswith("# racadm getversion"),
            icmc))
        # skip header
        next(icmc)
        # take all servers
        server_list.extend(itertools.takewhile(
            lambda line: line.startswith("server-"),
            icmc))
    except StopIteration:
        pass
    return server_list

print(scan_server_list(cmclog))

def scan_server_list_2(cmclog):
    icmc = iter(cmclog)
    # drop everything through the racadm sentinal
    next(itertools.dropwhile(
        lambda line: not line.startswith("# racadm getversion"),
        icmc))
    # skip header
    next(icmc)
    # take all servers
    yield from itertools.takewhile(
        lambda line: line.startswith("server-"),
        icmc)

print(list(scan_server_list_2(cmclog)))
```